# I need to prove that any element in a rings is representable as a product of some element and some central idempotent

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be an associative ring with identity and let $x$ be an arbitrary element from the ring $R$. Could you please help me to prove that $x=ye$, where $y$ is some element in $R$ and $e$ is some primitive central idempotent in $R$. In other words, I need to prove that any element in $R$ is representable as a product of some element and some primitive central idempotent in $R$.

Thanks for the answers! Answers like "you are not right, for example ..." and "see /book/, p. /page number/" are also OK.

Comment: I was about to post a (completely trivial) answer but then realized this is probably homework.

Comment: To Steven Landsburg:

I'm 30 (probably, too old for homeworks :)) I'm a installation developer in a small IT company, rings theory is just not my field. 

However, if you tell me the answer is simple, I probably can easily find it in a book. I'll try.

Anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @ingrem: Why is a *30 years old installation developer in a small IT company* interested in this? This is not a rhetorical question, I am genuinely curious. Related is http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask#motivation.

Comment: @Didier Piau:
10 years ago, when I was a student, I wrote a short paper about generic norms of finite-dimension associative algebras and their relations to Jacobson radical (such norms were studied by N. Jacobson, his papers were published in Osaka Math. Journal, search http://www.math.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp for details). Today, my old friend from the university (he is a lecturer in physics) asked me to explain something in that my old paper. I tried, but last 10 years ring theory was not my field, so some obvious facts about rings are not obvious for me anymore :) So, I asked the question.

Comment: "Ring theory is not my field". Heh.

Comment: @Dan Petersen:
Ring theory was my field 10 years ago. Enough time to forgot even simple things. Now my field is MS AppV, Citrix Virtualization, and Windows Installer :) If somebody is interested in this stuff, please let me know :)

Comment: Is this really true? What about $\mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}$ (the ring of all countable sequences of rationals, with coordinatewise addition and multiplication) and $x=\left(1,1,1,...\right)$ (the unity of the ring)?

Comment: Darij:  Why not just take R = Z/6Z ?

Comment: There is no kill like overkill. :)

Comment: @darij grinberg:
Thanks for your example. I'm not sure if it is really true. May be it is not. Obviously, the nonzero primitive idempotents in your example are $(1, 0, 0, \ldots)$, $(0,1,0,\dots)$ etc. Taking this into account, we obviously can't represent e.g. $(1,1,0,\ldots)$ as a product of a primitive central idempotent and some element. Hmmm... It looks like you answered my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ingrem: Thanks for your answer (though I do not quite understand whether the paper you wrote ten years ago got published somewhere or not).

Comment: @Didier Piau: That my work was published in Russian in a local university journal. Here, in ex-USSR, we usually called such local journals "мурзилка" ("murzilka", the name of really popular USSR journal for kids) because they have no web sites, no English versions, and nobody cites papers from these journals :)

Comment: Dear ingrem, when Dan Petersen quoted your "Ring theory is not my field" and added "Heh", I think he was just making a harmless little joke on the double meaning of "field". Sorry if it was obvious to you, but since English might not be your native language, I thought I might spell this out.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg: Sorry, I have no sense of humor at all. Sometimes it makes me looking stupid in situations like this.

Comment: @ingrem: Privet! My guess is that nobody here thought you were *stupid* (sic) because you missed Dan's linguistic pun. For many MO users, English is *not* their native language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the direct product $k\times k$ of two copies of some field and the element $x=(1,1)$. In this simple example you can describe all primitive central idempotents.